# Continuous Inegrable Function of R

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, inequality

Let f be a continuous integrable function of R such that either $f(x) > 0$ or $f(x) + f(x + 1) > 0$ for all x∈R, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx > 0$.

Is it true? Why or why not?

Comment: Please format your question so that it become readable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A := \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d}x $ and 
suppose that $A<0$.

$I := \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} max[f(x),f(x)+f(x+1)] \mathrm{d}x > 0$

$max(a,b) = \frac{1}{2} ( |a-b|+a+b) $, hence we have:

$I = \frac{1}{2}\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}[ |f(x)- (f(x)+f(x+1))| + f(x) + (f(x) + f(x+1) ] \mathrm{d}x > 0 $

$\frac{1}{2}\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}[ |f(x+1)|+ 2f(x) +  f(x+1)]\mathrm{d}x > 0$

$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x+1)|\mathrm{d}x + 2\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d}x +  \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+1) \mathrm{d}x  > 0$

$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x+1)|  \mathrm{d}x + 3A >0  $ (*)

We define: $f_{+}(x) := max (f(x), 0), f_{-}(x) := min (f(x), 0)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

But $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x+1)| \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|\mathrm{d}x =  
\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{+}(x)\mathrm{d}x  - \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{-}(x)\mathrm{d}x \leq |A|+|A| = 2|A| $ contradiction with (*) because we supposed that $A<0$.

Comment: I don't understand the estimate $\int f_+ -\int f_- \leq |A|+|A|$. Could you explain?

Comment: $-f \leq f_{+} \leq f$  and

$-f \leq -f_{-} \leq f$

hence $\int -f \leq \int  f_{+} \leq \int  f$

hence $-A \leq \int  f_{+} \leq A$

$|\int  f_{+}|  \leq |A| $

similarly $|- \int  f_{-}|  \leq |A| $

Hence $\int  f_{+} - \int  f_{-} \leq |A|+|A|=2|A|$

Comment: $f_+\leq f $ does not hold in general. In fact, the reverse inequality is true (by definition of $f_+$. Actually, you have $\int f_+ -\int f_- =\int |f| >0$ if $f $ does not vanish a.e. But you can still have $A=0$ in general, so your estimate is not true in general.